# Microsoft UAA Bus Driver for High Definition Audio

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio, sp3

Here are my specs first:

- ECS P4M800PRO-M478 (V1.0)
- Intel P4 Northwood 2.8 GHz
- 2x 512MB PC2-4200 DDR2-533 SDRAM
- Maxtor 120 GB SATA HDD
- Visiontek HD 3650 512 MB DDR2 AGP

I have `Microsoft UAA Bus Driver for High Definition Audio` as a system device without a driver. However, I don't know where to get an "official" driver for this "device". It just seems so generic. However, I noticed that when I had the video card in another machine, that machine required the same driver. Still, I've downloaded all possible video drivers and that device still needs a driver.

Where can I find it?

**EDIT 1:** Formatted hard drive, installed XP with the bare essentials, then installed the card & drivers... still the same problem.

**EDIT 2:** Installed the ATi HDMI Audio Driver after the UAA driver installation failed, due to XP  being SP3 already. Now, the "Found New Hardware" dialog that pops up on start-up doesn't come up anymore, but in the Device Manager, I still get an (!) by `Microsoft UAA Bus Driver for High Definition Audio`. Hmph...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the audio has always worked... just had a bad cable. Still, the Device Manager still listed a driver conflict with the UAA High Definition Audio and it was never resolved. Switching over the Windows 7 Home Premium, drivers were automatically found and there were no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

The "UAA Driver" is the generic class *audio* driver.  Video drivers aren't going to help you.  You'll most likely have to get the audio driver from your motherboard manufacturers website.

There is one caveat: ATI video cards (like the one you have) can pass audio over HDMI, and have an embedded audio codec to do that, which does require a driver.  Normally this is packaged in with the latest ATI Catalyst drivers.  I have seen the driver offered standalone before though...

...

Ah!  It's [here](http://game.amd.com/us-en/drivers_catalyst.aspx?p=xp/hdmiaudio-xp).

Comment: The first download is useless since I'm using XP SP3 and I installed the second one, but no difference... my video card doesn't even have native HDMI. I just have an eBay DVI-HDMI adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should download and install the related audio driver for your motherboard. In your motherboard's [official product page](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=580&CategoryID=1&MenuID=18&LanID=0), navigate to Download tab, and expand Sound panel. There are links to [Realtek AC'97 Audio Driver](http://eudownload.ecs.com.tw/dlfileecs/driver/industrial_mb/sound/AC97.zip) (19.9 MB).

Comment: I have installed all the drivers already. I wouldn't be asking this question if I didn't.

Comment: What exact problem are you experiencing then? Doesn't your PC play sounds or videos properly?

Comment: No sound... even though I reinstalled the driver without any audio plugs connected.

Comment: Sound works, UAA still doesn't have driver...